# map is not a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I've been trying for three days to solve that I can not put several elements in an array,but if I can put only one When I put in the return `this.state.dat.nombre` or `dat.carrera` it works, but if I try to put with the map function I do not get

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dat: [],
      isFetch: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var url =
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://sipla.cuci.udg.mx/sc/horariop.php?c=219359735&k=0d8ce4fab5f4df9ce711cae81e044e1a";

    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(art => {
        this.setState({ dat: art, isFetch: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isFetch) {
      return "cargando....";
    }

    this.state.dat.map(art => {
      return (
        <tr key={art.codigo}>
          <td>{art.nombre}</td>
          <td>{art.carrera}</td>
          <td>{art.horarios}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Error]

Comment: well log what `art` is when you set it. Is it an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I checked your API, I got this data

```
{
    carrera: "INGENIERIA EN COMPUTACION"
    ciclo_ingreso: "2019A"
    clave_carrera: "INCO"
    codigo: "219359735"
    cu: "CENTRO UNIVERSITARIO DE LA CIENEGA"
    estatus: "ACTIVO"
    fecha_consulta: "2019-07-12 12:20:20"
    horarios: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    nivel: "LICENCIATURA"
    nombre: "MARIA CECILIA PEREZ PEREZ"
    sede: "CAMPUS OCOTLAN"
    ultimo_ciclo: "2019B"
}
```

This is not array. `map` function for array.

If you want to use this data, you can just write like this.

```
render() {

    if(this.state.isFetch){
        return 'cargando....'
    }
    const {dat} = this.state;
    return (
        <tr key={dat.codigo}>
          <td>{dat.nombre}</td>
          <td>{dat.carrera}</td>
          <td>{dat.horarios}</td>
        </tr>
     );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just copy this code and run, you will get desired answer

````
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dat: [],
      isFetch: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let dat = []
    var url =
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://sipla.cuci.udg.mx/sc/horariop.php?c=219359735&k=0d8ce4fab5f4df9ce711cae81e044e1a";

    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(art => {
        dat.push(art)
        this.setState({ dat, isFetch: false });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isFetch) {
      return "cargando....";
    }

    this.state.dat.map(art => {
      return (
        <tr key={art.codigo}>
          <td>{art.nombre}</td>
          <td>{art.carrera}</td>
          <td>{art.horarios}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
}

export default App;```
````